# CheckBox function for same ss billing sddress

Tags: angularjs

i know its very common and very easy thing but really i m very new to angularjs and need your help

My View Page:

```
    <div ng-controller="AddressController">
        <div class="form-part-title" ng-show="Caption">{{Caption}} <span ng-show="showSameAsBilling" class="spancheck"><input type="checkbox" id="SameAsBilling" ng-model="Address.SameAsBilling"><label class=" after">Same As Billing Address</label></span> </div>
        <div ng-show="!readOnly">
            <label class="required">@Resource.Country<span ng-show="showInvalidAddress" class="spancheck"><input type="checkbox" id="InvalidAddress" ng-model="Address.InvalidAddress"><label class="after">Invalid Address</label></span>
                <span ng-show="showPostalOnly" class="spancheck"><input type="checkbox" id="PostalOnly" ng-model="Address.PostalOnly"><label class="after">Postal Only</label></span>
                </label>
            <select kendo-drop-down-list class="sdk-dropdown" ng-model="Address.CountryId" k-options="countries" k-on-change="onChange(kendoEvent)" />
            <label>@Resource.Address</label>
            <input class="block" type="text" name="Address" ng-model="Address.Address1" maxlength="100" />
            <input class="block" type="text" ng-model="Address.Address2" maxlength="100" />
            <input class="block" type="text" ng-model="Address.Address3" maxlength="100" />
            <label id="lblState">{{StateLabel}}</label>
            <select kendo-drop-down-list class="sdk-dropdown" ng-model="Address.StateProvinceId" k-options="states" k-rebind="states" />
            <label>@Resource.City</label>
            <input class="block" type="text" name="City" ng-model="Address.City" maxlength="50" />
            <label>{{ZipCodeLabel}}</label>
            <input class="block" type="text" name="ZipCode" ng-model="Address.ZipCode" maxlength="50" />
        </div>
        <div ng-show="readOnly">

            <textarea style="min-height:120px!important" disabled>{{Address.Address}}{{Address.Address1}} 
{{Address.Address2}}
{{Address.City}}
{{Address.State}}{{Address.CountryName}}
{{Address.ZipCode}}</textarea>
        </div>
</div>
```

My Angular Controller:

```
var AddressController = function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) {


    $scope.StateLabel = "State";
    $scope.ZipCodeLabel = "Zip Code";
    $scope.countryDataSource = {
        transport: {
            read: {
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/ApplicationData/GetCountries",
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.countries = {
        dataSource: $scope.countryDataSource,
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "Id",
        optionLabel: "Select..."

    };
    this.showAlert = function () {
        alert("this is test method");
    };

    $scope.onChange = function (e) {
        var countryId = e.sender.value();
        if (countryId == 2) {
            $scope.StateLabel = "Province";
            $scope.ZipCodeLabel = "Postal Code";
        }
        else {
            $scope.StateLabel = "State";
            $scope.ZipCodeLabel = "Zip Code";
        }

        $http.get('/ApplicationData/GetStates/' + countryId).
          success(function (jsonData, status, headers, config) {
              console.log(jsonData);
              var data = {
                  dataSource: jsonData,
                  dataTextField: "Name",
                  dataValueField: "Id",
                  optionLabel: "Select..."
              };

              $scope.states = data;
          }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("error getting countries");
            });
    };


    $scope.SameAsBilling = function (checked) {
        alert(1);
        if (SameAsBilling.checked = true) {
            vmCustomer.BillingAddress = vmCustomer.ShippingAddress
        }
    };

};
AddressController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location'];
```

i need you guys to help me with the below function

```
$scope.SameAsBilling = function (checked) {
    alert(1);
    if (SameAsBilling.checked = true) {
        vmCustomer.BillingAddress = vmCustomer.ShippingAddress
    }
};
```

i m tying but don't know why the check box is not talking to controller please help

Comment: could you remove the commented code please.. from html

Comment: its done, i removed commented part

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Zq7k6MQC55GGIg3QQKPx?p=info

Comment: plunkr is not really working dude..

Comment: I wont be able to help unless you provide what exact issue you are facing..

Comment: i need to copy whatever is in billing side as shipping side as soon as someone checks the check box if check box is un-select then shipping side should become empty again
i dont know why plunker is not working,